# Data type for mixed representation

Tags: postgis, postgresql, csv, ruby

The following is a JSON representation of an large array of planar spatial surfaces.

```
{"type":"Feature",
  "geometry":{
    "type":"MultiPolygon",
    "coordinates":
      [[[[17.7529,-31.146],[17.9742,-30.9097],[17.9783,-30.7836],[18.0728,-30.7795],[18.1533,-30.8411],[18.245,-30.8067],[18.3456,-30.6569],[18.3967,-30.5128],[18.5503,-30.4289],[18.6436,-30.5436],[18.7428,-30.5625],[18.7678,-30.6539],[18.8481,-30.7147],[18.9386,-30.7242],[18.9667,-30.9292],[18.8858,-31.03],[18.9364,-31.1072],[18.9269,-31.2161],[19.0139,-31.3694],[19.0639,-31.5083],[19.0869,-31.7522],[19.0311,-31.8328],[19.0883,-31.8969],[19.293,-31.9775],[19.3217,-32.0317],[19.4822,-32.0814],[19.4961,-32.2456],[19.3989,-32.2922],[19.4917,-32.4711],[19.4728,-32.5836],[19.5953,-32.6236],[19.605,-32.4908],[19.7944,-32.387],[19.9222,-32.3739],[20.0386,-32.2497],[20.1644,-32.1758],[20.2178,-32.2306],[20.1494,-32.3728],[20.0647,-32.4389],[20.1761,-32.7578],[20.2717,-32.7917],[20.4211,-32.9369],[20.5564,-32.8844],[20.5964,-32.9367],[20.7181,-32.9283],[20.8206,-32.8108],[20.7953,-32.6967],[20.9678,-32.6369],[21.1611,-32.613],[21.1922,-32.4592],[21.3231,-32.3736],[21.5469,-32.305],[21.5375,-32.2236],[21.7236,-32.1981],[21.8506,-32.2619],[21.9986,-32.1881],[22.0019,-32.0978],[22.1233,-32.05],[22.0636,-31.9203],[22.1653,-31.8786],[22.1711,-31.7758],[22.2914,-31.5703],[22.5922,-31.725],[22.565,-31.8005],[22.7233,-31.8022],[23.0464,-31.8853],[23.0697,-31.9767],[23.2139,-31.8681],[23.2664,-31.7425],[23.4008,-31.6814],[23.5097,-31.6994],[23.5847,-31.6544],[23.7258,-31.6589],[23.8261,-31.7256],[23.8567,-31.8233],[24.0206,-31.7281],[24.1469,-31.79],[24.1522,-31.895],[24.205,-31.9472],[24.0872,-32.0906],[24.0719,-32.1556],[23.8736,-32.2461],[23.7519,-32.1767],[23.6539,-32.2353],[23.6458,-32.3336],[23.4325,-32.3283],[23.2081,-32.4247],[23.2678,-32.5342],[23.3633,-32.8264],[23.1781,-32.7894],[23.0778,-32.8781],[22.9381,-32.9425],[22.9364,-33.0914],[22.8806,-33.1372],[22.7633,-33.3169],[22.7494,-33.4017],[22.8972,-33.4145],[23.0394,-33.3833],[23.2925,-33.3903],[23.3236,-33.432],[23.48,-33.4344],[23.5747,-33.4886],[23.655,-33.6175],[23.4125,-33.7133],[23.465,-33.7967],[23.6867,-33.8722],[23.6395,-33.9821],[23.449,-34.0051],[23.3649,-34.1051],[23.2251,-34.0871],[22.959,-34.0887],[22.9149,-34.0646],[22.564,-33.9962],[22.4851,-34.0526],[22.2371,-34.0576],[22.1232,-34.1165],[22.1135,-34.2049],[21.931,-34.2451],[21.8696,-34.364],[21.6954,-34.3957],[21.5368,-34.3568],[21.4446,-34.3682],[21.3051,-34.441],[21.0015,-34.3649],[20.8537,-34.3976],[20.8474,-34.4751],[20.6626,-34.4493],[20.5338,-34.4701],[20.4007,-34.5724],[20.0829,-34.7332],[19.9904,-34.8351],[19.8751,-34.7668],[19.6329,-34.7551],[19.4485,-34.6551],[19.354,-34.4774],[19.2713,-34.4093],[19.1226,-34.4185],[19.0376,-34.3412],[18.911,-34.3574],[18.8132,-34.1007],[18.7126,-34.0721],[18.4946,-34.0988],[18.3804,-34.2624],[18.3304,-34.024],[18.3976,-33.8993],[18.4854,-33.8415],[18.4376,-33.6929],[18.3154,-33.5096],[18.0974,-33.2301],[17.9696,-33.1376],[17.9915,-32.9965],[17.871,-32.991],[17.8957,-32.7429],[17.9796,-32.7268],[18.129,-32.7774],[18.2479,-32.6774],[18.3349,-32.4587],[18.3135,-32.3171],[18.3457,-32.281],[18.2257,-31.7507],[18.1165,-31.5829],[17.899,-31.351],[17.879,-31.2801],[17.7529,-31.146]]],[[[37.9069,-46.8996],[37.8564,-46.9683],[37.657,-46.9744],[37.5803,-46.9364],[37.6894,-46.8239],[37.8047,-46.8372],[37.9069,-46.8996]]]]
    },
    "properties":{
      "name":"Western Cape",
      "id":"ZA-WC",
      "CNTRY":"South Africa",
      "TYPE":"Province"
    },
    "id":"ZA-WC"
},
{"type":"Feature",
  "geometry":{
    "type":"Polygon",
    "coordinates":
      [[[-2.1512,49.2607],[-2.1353,49.2535],[-2.1049,49.2506],[-2.1013,49.2558],[-2.0913,49.2536],[-2.0801,49.2393],[-2.0731,49.2377],[-2.0529,49.2423],[-2.0414,49.2363],[-2.0253,49.2321],[-2.024,49.2271],[-2.03,49.2163],[-2.0179,49.2003],[-2.0283,49.1982],[-2.033,49.182],[-2.0277,49.1679],[-2.0332,49.1644],[-2.054,49.17],[-2.0782,49.1635],[-2.0917,49.1751],[-2.0985,49.1779],[-2.111,49.1764],[-2.1186,49.189],[-2.1311,49.1948],[-2.1421,49.1968],[-2.1595,49.1959],[-2.1692,49.1891],[-2.1695,49.1789],[-2.175,49.1717],[-2.1887,49.1765],[-2.19,49.1835],[-2.2018,49.185],[-2.204,49.1788],[-2.2234,49.1748],[-2.2435,49.1818],[-2.2309,49.1892],[-2.2233,49.2044],[-2.2307,49.2255],[-2.2421,49.2388],[-2.2535,49.2476],[-2.2538,49.2528],[-2.2425,49.259],[-2.211,49.2549],[-2.1974,49.2495],[-2.1826,49.2495],[-2.1704,49.2539],[-2.1653,49.259],[-2.1512,49.2607]]]
    },
    "properties":{
      "name":"Jersey",
      "id":"JE",
      "TYPE":"Jersey",
      "CNTRY":"Jersey"
    },
    "id":"JE"
},
```

While [this documentation describes representations](https://postgis.net/docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#RefObject)  POLYGON and MULTIPOLYGON, how should this table should be created as the object will have coordinates, assuming using [Rails' PostGIS adapter](https://github.com/rgeo/activerecord-postgis-adapter)

```
create_table :my_spatial_table do |t|
  t.st_polygon :the_shape, , srid: -1
  [and/or]
  t.multi_polygon :the_multi_shape, srid: -1
  t.string :name
  t.string :id
  t.string :country
  t.string :type
  t.boolean :multi
 end
```

Intuitively, I would go with the multi_polygon  allowing for records with a single polygon defined.  However this appears to be at odds with the examples of text representations (logically, 2 parenthesis for polygon, 3 for multipolygon) the documentation; it appears postgresql is expecting a specific format.   Naturally, this is intrinsincly linked to the import of the data.

Assuming this data is transformed into a CSV file, how should the table be created

- with 1 MULTIPOLYGON attribute , or,
- with 2 attributes, 1 MULTIPOLYGON and the other POLYGON with a boolean descriptor allowing queries to focus on one attribute of the other?

And how should the data be represented for proper digestion by PostgreSQL in the import process (parenthesis in lieu of square brackets and in relevant numbers, I assume), particluarly if one choose the single MULTIPOLYGON datatype ?

Comment: Create geometry column in PostGIS as multipolygon and cast polygons of the source data into multipolygons before inserting them. For example ogr2ogr https://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html can do that automatically with `-nlt PROMOTE_TO:MULTI`. Another option is to create the geometry column in PostGIS as general "geometry" when it will accept any kind of geometries.

Comment: should the arrays be cast with parenthesis or will square brackets do?

Comment: If you want to manipulate the original GeoJSON data you can find an example from here https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7946#appendix-A.6.